# Confirmed nginx server blocks are working but one domain is still pointing back at the default web root

Tags: nginx, centos7, nginx-config

Currently i have two domains pointed at this server
website1 and website2

So the second website will go to its server block files as should
However the first one is still going back to the default location and i cannot locate where in the config files it would still be pointing to it

nginx.conf
https://paste.centos.org/view/752c15c1

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/
 
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
 
# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;
 
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
 
http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
 
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
 
    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
 
    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;
 
    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
   
    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        #root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
        #root /var/www/nerdarcadia/html;
 
        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
 
        location / {
        }
 
        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }
 
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
 
# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        location / {
#        }
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }
 
}
```

website1.conf
https://paste.centos.org/view/03dd5162

```
server {
        listen  80;
        server_name nerdarcadia.com www.nerdarcadia.com;
 
        #charset
        #access_log /var/log/nginx/host.access.log main;
 
        location / {
                root /var/www/nerdarcadia/html
                index index.html index.htm;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
 
        #error_page 404 /404.html;
 
        #redirect server error pages
        #
        ###########
        ###BLANK###
        ###########
```

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files and ensure that both `server` blocks with the correct `server_name` appear.

Comment: @RichardSmith https://paste.centos.org/view/f2a715be

Comment: @RichardSmith its like its not pulling the first config. Permissions?

Comment: The configuration files are pulled in using `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;`. So, does the configuration file exist in `sites-enabled` and does it end with `.conf`? A common mistake is creating the files in `sites-available` and forgetting to create a symlink to `sites-enabled`.

Comment: @RichardSmith ya thats what i noticed when i looked in enabled. the sym link was broken but there was an error in the file. I got tired of looking for a syntax issue so i just copied the working one for the second site lolol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way i solved it was using the config for the site that was working. I'm not sure what changed but a lot of these tutorials have out of date formats that throw errors
For anyone looking to "just get the server block working" this is what i used

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/website2/html;

    index index.html;

    server_name website2.com www.website2.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;
```

Also make sure your sym link isn't broken between sites available/enabled folders